# Automating file treatment between multiple programmes

Tags: r, csv, user-interface, automation, calc

I'm trying to find a way to automate a series of processes that uses several different programmes. (Indifferently on Ubuntu and Windows).

For each programme, I've boiled the process down to either a macro or a script in each programme, so I feel confident that the entire process can be almost entirely automated. I just can't figure out what I can do to create a unifying tool.

The process is the following;

I have a simple text file with data, I use a jedit macro to tidy the data. This then goes to a OpenCalc template to create a graph, that data is then imported to a programme called TXM which (after many clicks) generates a column of data, this is exported to a csv file, that csv file is imported to an R session where upon a script is executed.

I have to repeat this process( and a few more similarones) dozens of times a day, and it's driving me nuts.

My research into how to automate the import treatment export process has shown a few glimmers of hope but I haven't been able to make any real progress.

I tried Autoexpect, but couldn't make it work on Ubuntu. TCL, I think only works for internet applications, Fabric I also haven't been able to make work.

I'm willing to spend a lot of time learning and develloping a tool to achieve this, but at the moment I'm not even sure what terms to search for.

Comment: please first try something yourself, then post your problems here.

Comment: That is the very nut of the problem; I've tried and seen that Autoexpect, TCL and Fabric won't work. I'm now out of searchable terms to find the beginning of a solution.

Comment: Probably just import your text file into and r session and do everything in R. You'll have to learn some R though.

Comment: Do you want to automated triggering your scripts (workflow) on a remote Ubuntu and/or Windows machine from a centralised server?
OR
Do you want to automated the scripts for your workflow: text_file -> jedit -> opencalc -> txm -> R ?

Comment: I want to automate the scripts for my workflow; I'd like to be able to go from the text file to the execution of the R script without having to manually copy, paste, export, import and open each programme. With regard to just using R, I still need to tidy the data using a text editor, (using a macro).

Comment: I've figured it out for windows; I created a .bat file in a text editor which, when click prompt the user for names, etc and rewrites another text file. It then executes that txt file as a script with r with the command R.exe CMD BATCH file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out for windows; I created a .bat file in a text editor which, when click prompst the user for names, etc and rewrites another text file. It then executes that .txt file as a script with r with the
`command R.exe CMD BATCH c:\user\desktop\mymacro.txt`